# Commit went into multiple branches, trying to revert branch to its inital state

Tags: svn, conflict

A switch went wrong and I committed some  files to a a different branch instead of the trunk; yet some other dirs made it to the trunk.

How do I revert the branch to its previous state?

I went into the branch and wanted to reverse merge:

`/fnord/foo/thisFolderShouldNotBeHereButInTrunk`

```
svn merge -r 5651:5650 fnord/foo/
--- Reverse-merging r5651 into '.':
   C foo
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
```

This folder was added by the commit. It should have been added in the trunk though. And I did exactly that already. Was that my mistake?

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A half switched checkout happens sometimes. Usually when the switch aborts halfway of you switch just one file or folder in stead of the entire working copy.

A mistake like this is best fixed manually. Just switch the entire working copy to the branch and remove the folder(s) yourself using `svn remove` and commit that change to the branch. You can then switch back to trunk and add the directory there by hand or merge the revision that added the folder(s) to the branch by mistake.